# Handle touch event in uiimage in uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I am drawing one image (called image1) on top of the another image (called main image) And saved that image locally. Now I am loading the "main image" in the UIWebview. It is fine. But now I need to handle event when touch on the "image1".
Please help me.

Thanks,
Jasmine.

Comment: how are you loading an image to UIWebview. can you put some code

Comment: I am converting that image as NSdata and load that data in uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**EDITED** 
create a UIWebView object  'webview' and create a  UITapGestureRecognizer object 'TapGesture'

then

```
    TapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
    TapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  TapGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.webview TapGesture];
```

In this case once you click the image it will call 'tapAction ' method ,In that you can add your code

in TapAction you can add

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
     {
         // you can add zooming frame here
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

      [self performTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve];
}
];
```

Comment: But i want to zoom that image also..SO i have loaded that image in UIWebView.

Comment: Can you add the tapGesture on the UIWebView and check

Comment: if u need like that then instead of UIIMageView  object  use UIWebview object and try the same code. and in tapAction method add somecode to zoom image do u have tha code for zooming?

Comment: @Navi.. Thanks for the Reply.. But the problem here is , I want to know the exact position of the "image" which is top of the mainimage. for ex. the size for the mainimage is 320x480. and I am drawing the image on at the point of (100,100) on the top of mainimage. Added mainimage in the Webview. Now when Zoom the Webview, the Mainimage also zooms. But I want to get the exact position where the "image1" is displays. It will not be in the point of (100,100).